# php image upload with spaced file name

Tags: php, file-upload, parse-platform

I'm having problem with image upload, i'm using parse as backend and everything is working, but i realize if filename is with space like "this is img.jpg" the uploader is not working, this is actual code

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    if (strlen($_FILES['image']['name'])>3) {
      $image = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
      $content->set("image", $image);
      @unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    }
  }
```

i tried to use str_replace but still is not working, i get blank page, i think im doin something wrong

```
  if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    if (strlen($_FILES['image']['name'])>3) {
      $image = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
      $img = str_replace(' ', '_', $image);
      $content->set("image", $img);
      @unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: blank page means syntax errors, usually. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and remove `@` symbols, they're error suppressors.

Comment: 1) what is $content? 2) why didn't you use move_uploaded_file()? 3) unlink is overhead, the garbecollector will do this for you

Comment: @donald123 because i didn't know, im not php developer

Comment: I don't see $img in your 2nd example defined anywhere. That might be causing issues.

Comment: @donald123 $content is parseObject where the file will be saved, $content = new ParseObject("contents");

Comment: for beginning ... use **use move_uploaded_file()** to deal with uploads, there are x examples google file upload php and your will see how to handle

Comment: still im gettin error if i try to upload file wich is named with space